# StageXL GraphicsGradient

Tags: dart, stagexl

A gradient created using GraphicsGradient seems to always produce a pink colour with no actual gradient. I have copied the code from StageXL /example/example06/example06.dart, changing the TransitionFunction to Transition. I have also modified the Stage slightly to fit in with my plans and played around with different colours.

The code I am using is this:

```
import 'dart:html' as html;
import 'package:stagexl/stagexl.dart';

void main()
{
  //------------------------------------------------------------------
  // Initialize the Display List
   //------------------------------------------------------------------

 Stage stage = new Stage(html.querySelector('#stage'),width: 800, height: 800);

   RenderLoop renderLoop = new RenderLoop();
   renderLoop.addStage(stage);

   //------------------------------------------------------------------
   // Draw a cloud with vectors
   //------------------------------------------------------------------

   var gradient = new GraphicsGradient.linear(230, 0, 370, 200);
   gradient.addColorStop(0, Color.LightBlue);
   gradient.addColorStop(1, Color.DarkBlue);

   Sprite sprite = new Sprite();
   sprite.useHandCursor = true;
   stage.addChild(sprite);

   Shape shape = new Shape();
   shape.pivotX = 278;
   shape.pivotY = 90;
   shape.x = 400;
   shape.y = 300;
   sprite.addChild(shape);

   shape.graphics
     ..beginPath()
     ..moveTo(170, 80)
     ..bezierCurveTo(130, 100, 130, 150, 230, 150)
     ..bezierCurveTo(250, 180, 320, 180, 340, 150)
     ..bezierCurveTo(420, 150, 420, 120, 390, 100)
     ..bezierCurveTo(430, 40, 370, 30, 340, 50)
     ..bezierCurveTo(320, 5, 250, 20, 250, 50)
     ..bezierCurveTo(200, 5, 150, 20, 170, 80)
     ..closePath()
     ..fillGradient(gradient)
     ..strokeColor(Color.Blue, 5);

   //------------------------------------------------------------------
   // Add some animation
   //------------------------------------------------------------------

   Tween tween1 = new Tween(shape, 3.0, Transition.easeInOutBack)
     ..animate.scaleX.to(2.5)
     ..animate.scaleY.to(2.5)
     ..delay = 1.0;

   Tween tween2 = new Tween(shape, 3.0, Transition.easeInOutBack)
     ..animate.scaleX.to(1.0)
     ..animate.scaleY.to(1.0)
     ..delay = 5.0;

   renderLoop.juggler.add(tween1);
   renderLoop.juggler.add(tween2);
 }
```

Any comments or help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is a restriction with the WebGL renderer in the current StageXL version. Only solid colors are supported for strokes and fills. Graphics gradients and patterns are only supported with the Canvas2D renderer. You could also use the applyCache method on your display object, which will render a temporary texture with Canvas2D that will also show the correct results with the WebGL renderer.

You can configure the renderer like this (do this before you create the Stage instance):

```
// to use the WebGL renderer (default)
StageXL.stageOptions.renderEngine = RenderEngine.WebGL;

// to use the Canvas2D renderer
StageXL.stageOptions.renderEngine = RenderEngine.Canvas2D;
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. I will work around this as suggested

Comment: Please be aware that the Canvas2D renderer may be slower compared to the WebGL renderer. The WebGL renderer is much faster if you use many BitmapData resources that share a common texture.

Answer (score 1):

After the helpful comments and trying both approaches I have decided to go down the applyCache() route as I want to keep the WebGL speed. My code for a hexagon sprite with a gradient fill comes out like this (where root3over2 is a globally defined constant):

```
Sprite getSprite(num x, num y, num hexSize) {

var gradient = new GraphicsGradient.linear(x-hexSize, y-hexSize, x + hexSize, y+ hexSize);
gradient.addColorStop(0, Color.BlanchedAlmond);
gradient.addColorStop(1, Color.Coral);

Sprite sprite = new Sprite()
   ..graphics.beginPath()
   ..graphics.moveTo( -1 * hexSize + x, y)
   ..graphics.lineTo(-0.5 * hexSize + x, root3over2 * hexSize  + y)
   ..graphics.lineTo(0.5 * hexSize + x, root3over2 * hexSize + y)
   ..graphics.lineTo(1 * hexSize + x, y)
   ..graphics.lineTo(0.5 * hexSize + x, -root3over2 * hexSize + y)
   ..graphics.lineTo(-0.5 * hexSize + x, -root3over2 * hexSize + y)
   ..graphics.closePath()
   ..graphics.fillGradient(gradient)
   ..graphics.strokeColor(Color.Black,2);

    sprite.applyCache(x - hexSize,y - hexSize, hexSize * 2, hexSize * 2);

    return sprite;
}
```